# Spring Boot + Hibernate: @Entity name ignored

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have a service build using Spring Boot + JPA/Hibernate.

I have two classes with the same name in different jars/packages.

Running the application using Eclipse was resulting in a **duplicate import** problem, so I added the following in one of the entities:

```
@Entity(name = "EnderecoCEP")
```

It solved the problem in Eclipse and I can run the application just fine. When running the Spring Boot generated jar using java -jar, though, the problem is back:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: duplicate import: Endereco refers to both b.c.c.c.e.Endereco and b.c.c.d.e.Endereco (try using auto-import="false")
```

Looks like @Entity(name) property is being completely ignored. I found a lot of posts complaining about similar issues (another JAR mapping), but none with a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question!

The problem was with the JAR version in my POM! 4 hours later!!!